# How to merge rows with similar values in datagaridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Good day everyone, can anyone help me with merging rows with similar values in datagridviewrow... I am making an application where if you select multiple items with similar item names, it must not add another row, instead it will just merge with the same row with same values, and it will add up the quantity and total. for clarity, this is the image.

[image]

Comment: What about starting by searching if there's any row with the same `P.O.#`, if yes update it else add a new row ?

Comment: So what is the coding issue you have?   If you are looking for a tutorial on basic data processing, then this is the wrong place to look.

Comment: Isnt that something you want to do in SQL?

Comment: SELECT NAME, SUM(SALARY) as [sum of salary] FROM CUSTOMERS 
   GROUP BY NAME;